# this.DebugSettings doesn't exist (switching off frame rate counter)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2022

I am trying to debug my Xamarin Forms app using UWP, but whenever the app launches in debug, a framerate counter appears on the window, obscuring the page title and access to the menu.

I have searched for solutions to this, but every result I get says to set

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
```

(for example: https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-turn-off-the-frame-rate-counters-for-windows-universal-apps/)

But "this" has no DebugSettings;  nether in the root project, or the UWP project.

How do I get rid of this extremely annoying "utility"?

Comment: It’s a property of the UWP Application object

Comment: Thanks. It didn't show up when searching through the solution for the text. The line is in the mail App.xaml.cs in the UWP project. Make an answer from your comment and I'll accept it.